# Deploy Spartacus to Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, spartacus-storefront

I'm been trying to deploy my SAP Spartacus app to Heroku.

In the scripts section of my package.json I have added `"start": "node server.ts",`

And this is the server.ts I'm using:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src/spartacus-mystore'));
app.get('/*', function (req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+
    '/src/spartacus-mystore/index.html'));});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I still donno what, but something is wrong with this file. In the Heroku's console I see everything is correct and the app was successfully deployed but when I reach it I just see a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this following this steps:

1. I added `"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"` to scripts section in package.json.
2. I copied @angular/compiler, @angular/compiler-cli, @angular-devkit/build-angular and @angular-devkit/schematics fron devDependencies to dependencies
3. I change my serve.ts according to Erik's comment

   const express = require('express');
   const path = require('path');
   const app = express();
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/mystore/browser'));
   app.get('/*', function (req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/dist/mystore/browser/index.html'));});
   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

Now it's working https://spartacus-mystore.herokuapp.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/

Comment: nice that you give yourself the answer 'karma'

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting the HTML back? Or just nothing.

I see you are running express on your src/ directory, why don't you build on your heroku instance and then statically serve the dist/ directory?

It might be that your backend is not approving the request from the Heroku URL, so the Spartacus is not receiving any data. CORS issues are pretty common here ;-)

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cors/#setting-up-cors

Comment: Hey Erik. I'm seeing the index.html, but the <app-root></app-root> is no taking effect. I don't see any dist/ directory in heroku app folder. Can you please explain more a little bit?

Comment: did you run ng build --prod on the server?